# How to run multiple Docker containers in AWS ECS, each with their own domain name and SSL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I host multiple websites, each with their own domain name, running as Docker containers. Currently, I have an EC2 instance running Docker with Traefik as a reverse proxy and for SSL termination.

I’m wanting to see if I can achieve the same thing with AWS ECS - run a series of standalone websites in Docker containers, each with their own domain name.

I’m finding it strangely hard to work out how join the dots together. It seems that I need an application load balancer, but once that’s in place, is it a case of each container having to run on a unique port and use a header rule to point the domain name at the right one?

Is there a simpler way to run a bunch of independent websites as Docker containers on AWS, each with their own domain name and SSL?

Comment: The "unique port" issue depends on the network mode you select for your ECS tasks. If you use `awsvpc` network mode then they can all run on the same port, since each task will have a separate network connection. You would use host based routing to route the traffic from the load balancer to the specific ECS task/container https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/

Comment: Thanks. I’ve experimented further but having some routing issues from ALB to the Internet which is stopping containers being pulled. It does seem to an area of missing documentation, giving a complete walkthrough of how to set it up, although I understand people can use it for many different setups.

Comment: "having some routing issues from ALB to the Internet which is stopping containers being pulled" is not a thing that can actually happen. ECS does not utilize the ALB when pulling containers from the Internet. The ALB is only ever utilized when serving requests that originate from outside. When ECS is trying to pull containers from the Internet, it either needs to be running with a public IP address in a subnet with a route to an Internet gateway, or it needs to be in a subnet with a route to a NAT Gateway.

Comment: Thanks, I have a suspicion I didn't create a NAT gateway - whoops! I'll have another go at setting it up.